# Optimize hundreds of dynamic lines in Three.js

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, 3d

I'm new to Three.js, I'm just having fun with it. I'm trying to achieve a simple dynamic background fullscreen on a page, you get [the example here](https://codepen.io/ThoughtsRiff/pen/MPyypJ):

```
function createHexagon( vertices, color ) {
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: color, opacity: Math.min((Math.random() / 5), 0.1), transparent: true } );

    var hexagon = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
    return hexagon;
}

function initMatrix() {
    var color = defaultColor.getHex();
    var vertices;

    var x = ( width / -2 ) - 90;
    var y = height / -2;
    var deltaX = 120;
    var deltaY = 60;
    var time = 5.0;
    while( y < height / 2 ) {
        while( x < width / 2 ) {

            vertices = new Float32Array([
                0,  30, 0,
               20,   0, 0
            ]);
            var hexagon = createHexagon( vertices, color );
            scene.add( hexagon );  
            hexagon.position.set( x, y, 0 );

            vertices = new Float32Array([
               20,   0, 0,
               60,   0, 0
            ]);
            var hexagon = createHexagon( vertices, color );
            scene.add( hexagon );  
            hexagon.position.set( x, y, 0 );

            vertices = new Float32Array([
               60,   0, 0,
               80,  30, 0
            ]);
            var hexagon = createHexagon( vertices, color );
            scene.add( hexagon );  
            hexagon.position.set( x, y, 0 );

            x += deltaX;

        }

        x = ( width / -2 ) - 90;
        y += deltaY;
    }

    x = ( width / -2 ) - 30;
    y = ( height / -2 ) - 30;
    deltaX = 120;
    deltaY = 60;
    while( y < height / 2 ) {
        while( x < width / 2 ) {

            vertices = new Float32Array([
                0,  30, 0,
               20,   0, 0
            ]);
            var hexagon = createHexagon( vertices, color );
            scene.add( hexagon );  
            hexagon.position.set( x, y, 0 );

            vertices = new Float32Array([
               20,   0, 0,
               60,   0, 0
            ]);
            var hexagon = createHexagon( vertices, color );
            scene.add( hexagon );  
            hexagon.position.set( x, y, 0 );

            vertices = new Float32Array([
               60,   0, 0,
               80,  30, 0
            ]);
            var hexagon = createHexagon( vertices, color );
            scene.add( hexagon );  
            hexagon.position.set( x, y, 0 );          

            x += deltaX;
        }

        x = ( width / -2 ) - 30;
        y += deltaY;
    }
}
```

Those are single bufferGeometry lines (as you can see in the above functions to create the background) that randomly rotate and change opacity on mouse hover with raycaster and TweenLite. It works pretty fine. What you can notice is that CPU usage goes to almost 100%.

I know that if I group lines into the same geometry it'll be better on performance, but then I'm not able to animate single lines with raycaster, especially the opacity.

I searched a lot of discussions and tried so many things. The best result is this way, rendering single lines separately. Can you suggest some tips about it?

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_drawcalls

Comment: @gman thank you for replying! I watched the example, I didn't figure out how to apply it to my case since it is an automated one and I need a mouse event dependent behavior. Anyway, I figure out how to achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I found a solution. I made a whole geometry and I indexed vertices and respective colors. The only problem is that I can't mange opacity this way, but it works fine and CPU is around 20%.

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', main );

var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;
var camera, scene, renderer, raycaster, mouse;
var rayColor = new THREE.Color( 0x0640C2 );
var rayColor2 = new THREE.Color( 0xCC311B );
var colors;
var linesPositions, originalPositions;
var linesMesh;
var geometry;
var intersects;

var stats;

function initMatrix() {

    var AlinesPositions = [ ];

    var x = ( width / - 2 ) - 80;
    var y = ( height / - 2 ) - 60;
    var deltaX = 120;
    var deltaY = 60;

    while( y <= ( height / 2 ) ) {

        while( x <= ( width / 2 ) ) {

            AlinesPositions.push( x, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );

            x += deltaX;

        }

        x = ( width / -2 ) - 80;
        y += deltaY;

    }

    x = ( width / - 2 );
    y = ( height / - 2 ) - 60;

    while( y <= ( height / 2 ) ) {

        while( x <= ( width / 2 ) ) {

            AlinesPositions.push( x, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );

            x += deltaX;

        }

        x = ( width / -2 );
        y += deltaY;

    }

    linesPositions = new Float32Array( AlinesPositions );

    var Acolors = [ ];
    for( var i = 0; i < AlinesPositions.length; i++ ) {

        var fact = Math.random() * 20.0;
        var ran = Math.min( Math.max( ( Math.random() / fact ), 0.01 ), 0.5 );
        Acolors[i] = ran;
        Acolors[i+1] = ran;
        Acolors[i+2] = ran;

        i += 2;
    }

    colors = new Float32Array( Acolors );

    geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( linesPositions, 3 ).setDynamic( true ) );
    geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ).setDynamic( true ) );

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent: true
    } );

    linesMesh = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry, material );
    scene.add( linesMesh );

    originalPositions = new THREE.BufferAttribute( linesPositions, 3 );
    originalPositions.copy( linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position );

}

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 1, 100 );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 120, width / height, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 200 );
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    // Create matrix
    initMatrix();

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.linePrecision = 20;

    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function main() {

    init();
    animate();

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();

}

var intersected = [];

function removeX( i ) { intersected.splice( i, 1 ); }

function alterate( index ) {

    var randColor = ( Math.random() <= 0.49 ) ? rayColor : rayColor2;
    // Change color
    var currentC = new THREE.Color( linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getX( index ), linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getY( index ), linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getZ( index ));
    var tweenC = TweenLite.to( currentC, 1.0, {

        r: randColor.r,
        g: randColor.g,
        b: randColor.b,
        immediateRender: true,
        lazy: false,
        onUpdate: function() {

            linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.setXYZ( index, currentC.r, currentC.g, currentC.b );
            linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;

        },
        onUpdateParams: [ index, currentC ]

    });

    // Change coordinates
    var currentXY = { x: originalPositions.getX( index ), y: originalPositions.getY( index ), z: originalPositions.getZ( index ) };
    var goal = [ ( currentXY.x + ( Math.random() * 50 ) * ( ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) ? 1 : -1 ) ), ( currentXY.y + ( Math.random() * 50 ) * ( ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) ? 1 : -1 ) ), ( currentXY.z + ( Math.random() * 50 ) * ( ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) ? 1 : -1 ) ) ];
    var tweenXY = TweenLite.to( currentXY, 1.0, {

        x: goal[ 0 ],
        y: goal[ 1 ],
        z: goal[ 2 ],
        immediateRender: true,
        lazy: false,
        onUpdate: function() {

            linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( index, currentXY.x, currentXY.y, currentXY.z );    
            linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

        },
        onUpdateParams: [ index, currentXY ]

    });

}

function render() {

    // update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( linesMesh );

    if( intersects.length ) {

        if( !intersected.includes( intersects[ 0 ].index ) ) {

            for( var x = 0; x < intersects.length; x++ ) {

                if( !intersected.includes( intersects[ x ].index ) ) {

                    var index = intersects[ x ].index;

                    // Save index
                    intersected.push( index );

                    alterate( index );

                }

            }

            var present = 0;

            for( var y = 0; y < intersected.length; y++ ) {

                for( var j = 0; j < intersects.length; j++ ) {

                    if( intersects[ j ].index == intersected[ y ] ) { present = 1; break; }

                }

                if( !present ) {

                    ( function( y ) { 

                        var randC = Math.min( Math.max( ( Math.random() / ( Math.random() * 20.0 ) ), 0.01 ), 0.5 );

                        // Current item old coordinates
                        let index = intersected[ y ];
                        var indexX = originalPositions.getX( index );
                        var indexY = originalPositions.getY( index );
                        var indexZ = originalPositions.getZ( index );

                        removeX( y );

                        // Reset color
                        var currentCreset = new THREE.Color( linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getX( index ), linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getY( index ), linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getZ( index ));
                        var tweenCreset = TweenLite.to( currentCreset, 1.5, {

                            r: randC,
                            g: randC,
                            b: randC,
                            immediateRender: true,
                            lazy: false,
                            onUpdate: function() {

                                linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.setXYZ( index, currentCreset.r, currentCreset.g, currentCreset.b );
                                linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;

                            },
                            onUpdateParams: [ index, currentCreset ],
                            onComplete: function() { }

                        } );

                        // Reset coordinates
                        var currentXYreset = { x: linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.getX( index ), y: linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.getY( index ), z: linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.getZ( index ) };
                        var tweenXYreset = TweenLite.to( currentXYreset, 1.5, {

                            x: indexX,
                            y: indexY,
                            z: indexZ,
                            immediateRender: true,
                            lazy: false,
                            onUpdate: function() {

                                linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( index, currentXYreset.x, currentXYreset.y, currentXYreset.z );    
                                linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

                            },
                            onUpdateParams: [ index, currentXYreset ]                       

                        });

                    }) ( y );

                }

            }

        }

    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

function onMouseMove( event ) {

    // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
    // (-1 to +1) for both components
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    var normX = event.clientX - ( window.innerWidth / 2 );
    var normY = event.clientY - ( window.innerHeight / 2 );

    camera.position.set( 0 + ( normY / 50 ), 0 + ( normX / 50 ), 200 );
    camera.lookAt( 0 + ( normY / 50 ), 0 + ( normX / 50 ), 0 );

}

window.addEventListener( 'click', function() {

    if( intersected.length ) {

        for( var x = 0; x < intersected.length; x++ ) {

            var index = intersected[ x ];

            alterate( index );

        }

    }

});

window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
// Set new dimensions for scene when resize window
window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() { 
    var wWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var wHeight = window.innerHeight;

    /*camera.left = wWidth / -2;
    camera.right = wWidth / 2;
    camera.top = wHeight / 2;
    camera.bottom = wHeight / -2;*/
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
} );
```

Here is a [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/ThoughtsRiff/pen/yRJgvv?editors=1111).

Comment: Should I have replied here?

Comment: Ideally yes, @ThoughtsRiff. We prefer answers to be separate from questions since: (1) they can be accepted and/or voted on, (2) they can be handled correctly by the data API. If you would like to copy + paste this answer, so it is under your own name, please do (if you do so, please let me know, so I can delete my wiki answer).

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sorry then. 
Ok, I copy/paste it, just to be precise. Thank you and sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I made a whole geometry and I indexed vertices and respective colors. The only problem is that I can't mange opacity this way, but it works fine and CPU is around 20%.

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', main );

var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;
var camera, scene, renderer, raycaster, mouse;
var rayColor = new THREE.Color( 0x0640C2 );
var rayColor2 = new THREE.Color( 0xCC311B );
var colors;
var linesPositions, originalPositions;
var linesMesh;
var geometry;
var intersects;

var stats;

function initMatrix() {

    var AlinesPositions = [ ];

    var x = ( width / - 2 ) - 80;
    var y = ( height / - 2 ) - 60;
    var deltaX = 120;
    var deltaY = 60;

    while( y <= ( height / 2 ) ) {

        while( x <= ( width / 2 ) ) {

            AlinesPositions.push( x, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );

            x += deltaX;

        }

        x = ( width / -2 ) - 80;
        y += deltaY;

    }

    x = ( width / - 2 );
    y = ( height / - 2 ) - 60;

    while( y <= ( height / 2 ) ) {

        while( x <= ( width / 2 ) ) {

            AlinesPositions.push( x, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x + 80, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y + 60, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );
            AlinesPositions.push( x, y, 0 /*Math.abs( ( 100 / ( width / 2 ) * x ) + ( 100 / ( height / 2 ) * y ) )*/ );

            x += deltaX;

        }

        x = ( width / -2 );
        y += deltaY;

    }

    linesPositions = new Float32Array( AlinesPositions );

    var Acolors = [ ];
    for( var i = 0; i < AlinesPositions.length; i++ ) {

        var fact = Math.random() * 20.0;
        var ran = Math.min( Math.max( ( Math.random() / fact ), 0.01 ), 0.5 );
        Acolors[i] = ran;
        Acolors[i+1] = ran;
        Acolors[i+2] = ran;

        i += 2;
    }

    colors = new Float32Array( Acolors );

    geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( linesPositions, 3 ).setDynamic( true ) );
    geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ).setDynamic( true ) );

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent: true
    } );

    linesMesh = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry, material );
    scene.add( linesMesh );

    originalPositions = new THREE.BufferAttribute( linesPositions, 3 );
    originalPositions.copy( linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position );

}

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 1, 100 );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 120, width / height, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 200 );
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    // Create matrix
    initMatrix();

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.linePrecision = 20;

    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function main() {

    init();
    animate();

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();

}

var intersected = [];

function removeX( i ) { intersected.splice( i, 1 ); }

function alterate( index ) {

    var randColor = ( Math.random() <= 0.49 ) ? rayColor : rayColor2;
    // Change color
    var currentC = new THREE.Color( linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getX( index ), linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getY( index ), linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getZ( index ));
    var tweenC = TweenLite.to( currentC, 1.0, {

        r: randColor.r,
        g: randColor.g,
        b: randColor.b,
        immediateRender: true,
        lazy: false,
        onUpdate: function() {

            linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.setXYZ( index, currentC.r, currentC.g, currentC.b );
            linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;

        },
        onUpdateParams: [ index, currentC ]

    });

    // Change coordinates
    var currentXY = { x: originalPositions.getX( index ), y: originalPositions.getY( index ), z: originalPositions.getZ( index ) };
    var goal = [ ( currentXY.x + ( Math.random() * 50 ) * ( ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) ? 1 : -1 ) ), ( currentXY.y + ( Math.random() * 50 ) * ( ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) ? 1 : -1 ) ), ( currentXY.z + ( Math.random() * 50 ) * ( ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) ? 1 : -1 ) ) ];
    var tweenXY = TweenLite.to( currentXY, 1.0, {

        x: goal[ 0 ],
        y: goal[ 1 ],
        z: goal[ 2 ],
        immediateRender: true,
        lazy: false,
        onUpdate: function() {

            linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( index, currentXY.x, currentXY.y, currentXY.z );    
            linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

        },
        onUpdateParams: [ index, currentXY ]

    });

}

function render() {

    // update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( linesMesh );

    if( intersects.length ) {

        if( !intersected.includes( intersects[ 0 ].index ) ) {

            for( var x = 0; x < intersects.length; x++ ) {

                if( !intersected.includes( intersects[ x ].index ) ) {

                    var index = intersects[ x ].index;

                    // Save index
                    intersected.push( index );

                    alterate( index );

                }

            }

            var present = 0;

            for( var y = 0; y < intersected.length; y++ ) {

                for( var j = 0; j < intersects.length; j++ ) {

                    if( intersects[ j ].index == intersected[ y ] ) { present = 1; break; }

                }

                if( !present ) {

                    ( function( y ) { 

                        var randC = Math.min( Math.max( ( Math.random() / ( Math.random() * 20.0 ) ), 0.01 ), 0.5 );

                        // Current item old coordinates
                        let index = intersected[ y ];
                        var indexX = originalPositions.getX( index );
                        var indexY = originalPositions.getY( index );
                        var indexZ = originalPositions.getZ( index );

                        removeX( y );

                        // Reset color
                        var currentCreset = new THREE.Color( linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getX( index ), linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getY( index ), linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.getZ( index ));
                        var tweenCreset = TweenLite.to( currentCreset, 1.5, {

                            r: randC,
                            g: randC,
                            b: randC,
                            immediateRender: true,
                            lazy: false,
                            onUpdate: function() {

                                linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.setXYZ( index, currentCreset.r, currentCreset.g, currentCreset.b );
                                linesMesh.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;

                            },
                            onUpdateParams: [ index, currentCreset ],
                            onComplete: function() { }

                        } );

                        // Reset coordinates
                        var currentXYreset = { x: linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.getX( index ), y: linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.getY( index ), z: linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.getZ( index ) };
                        var tweenXYreset = TweenLite.to( currentXYreset, 1.5, {

                            x: indexX,
                            y: indexY,
                            z: indexZ,
                            immediateRender: true,
                            lazy: false,
                            onUpdate: function() {

                                linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( index, currentXYreset.x, currentXYreset.y, currentXYreset.z );    
                                linesMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

                            },
                            onUpdateParams: [ index, currentXYreset ]                       

                        });

                    }) ( y );

                }

            }

        }

    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

function onMouseMove( event ) {

    // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
    // (-1 to +1) for both components
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    var normX = event.clientX - ( window.innerWidth / 2 );
    var normY = event.clientY - ( window.innerHeight / 2 );

    camera.position.set( 0 + ( normY / 50 ), 0 + ( normX / 50 ), 200 );
    camera.lookAt( 0 + ( normY / 50 ), 0 + ( normX / 50 ), 0 );

}

window.addEventListener( 'click', function() {

    if( intersected.length ) {

        for( var x = 0; x < intersected.length; x++ ) {

            var index = intersected[ x ];

            alterate( index );

        }

    }

});

window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
// Set new dimensions for scene when resize window
window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() { 
    var wWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var wHeight = window.innerHeight;

    /*camera.left = wWidth / -2;
    camera.right = wWidth / 2;
    camera.top = wHeight / 2;
    camera.bottom = wHeight / -2;*/
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
} );
```

Here is a Codepen link: [Example](https://codepen.io/ThoughtsRiff/pen/yRJgvv?editors=1111)